# VS Code Emmet suggestions are not working for "div.aa", but work for "div.a" and "div.aaa". Why?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, emmet

Normally when I type `div.a` it will create a tag that looks like this: `<div class="a"> </div>`

But I've been having a problem for the last few days. Similarly, when I type div.a, it gives me a small pop-up to create a tag [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUeBE.png).

But in the last few days, I noticed this: If I type `div.a`, this pop-up appears, but when I type `div.aa`, this pop-up disappears. And when I add a again it comes back. As someone who writes fast code, this is a big problem for me.

[Here's a little gif that summarizes the whole problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejK6t.gif)

To solve this problem, I turned off all my plugins, nothing changed. I know it's not related to a later plugin. I haven't made any changes to my computer either, strange.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. 2) I know you tried turning off all your extensions, but as a sanity check, does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.